# Преобразование результата запроса в структуру

Tags: golang

Есть несколько структур *(Users, Projects, Messages, etc)* с разным набором полей. Делаем запрос к базе, получаем *rows*, затем `for rows.Next() { rows.Scan(&поле1, &поле2) }` это понятно. Но хотелось бы избежать повторений кода для каждой структуры и сделать функцию, которая любой *Rows* преобразует в нужную структуру. Как это лучше реализовать?

Comment: Использовать ORM (например, GORM), либо что-то более легковесное [Dat](https://github.com/mgutz/dat), [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx)

Answer (score 1):

Нужен метод который будет принимать собственно `rows` или `row`. Предупреждаю сразу, что при том подходе, что я здесь описываю вносить изменения будет очень трудно. Итак поехали:

```go
// Если моделей много, то удобней вынести их в отдельный пакет

// Package models contains all sql-models
package models

import (
    // в моём примере используется PosqtgreSQL и эта библиотека
    "github.com/lib/pq"

    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

// Scanner - интерфейс необходим для того
// чтобы можно было испоьзовать одинаково
// *sql.Rows и *sql.Row
type Scanner interface {
    Scan(...interface{}) error
}

// Собственно тривиальная модель
type User struct {
    ID          int64
    FirstName   string
    LastName    string
    Email       string
    CreatedAt   time.Time
    UpdatedAt   time.Time
    DeletedAt   time.Time
}

// Эта функция будет использоваться для извлечения
// данных из rows.
func (u *User) Scan(row Scanner) error {

    // строка может быть NULL-ом
    var firstName sql.NullString
    var lastName sql.NullString

    // при этом Email в базе данных отмечен
    // как NOT NULL и переживать о том, что
    // он будет NULL-ом нет смысла

    // Время может быть NULL-ом. В этом случае
    // я использую фишку библиотеки github.com/lib/pq
    var createdAt pq.NullTime
    var updatedAt pq.NullTime
    var deletedAt pq.NullTime

    // Собственно сканирование
    err := row.Scan(
        &u.ID,
        &firstName, &lastName,
        &u.Email,
        &createdAt, &updatedAt, &deletedAt,
    )

    // ошибка сканнирования
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Проверка на валидность тех полей что
    // могут быть NULL-ом. В моём случае
    // я использую свеже-созданную структуру
    // и поэтому не сбрасываю значение, если оно
    // NULL.

    if firstName.Valid {
        u.FirstName = firstName.String
    }
    if lastName.Valid {
         u.LastName = lastName.String
     }
    if createdAt.Valid {
        u.CreatedAt = createdAt.Time
    }
    if updatedAt.Valid {
        u.UpdatedAt = updatedAt.Time
    }
    if deletedAt.Valid {
        u.DeletedAt = deletedAt.Time
    }
    return nil
}
```

Как пользоваться:

```
for rows.Next() {
     usr := new(User)
     if err := usr.Scan(rows); err != nil {
         rows.Close()
         return err
     }
     //
     // работа с заполненным пользователем
     //
}
```

Так же частенько возникает необходимость использовать сложные запросы типа `INNER JOIN` и так далее. Удобно сделать ещё пару функций - извлечение всех полей структуры как `[]interface{}` и присвоение их обратно. Если типы `NullString`, `NullTime` и подобные не использовать, то можно обойтись только одной функцией. Однако в SQL придётся везде вставлять `NOT NULL`, что далеко не всегда возможно/производительно.

Для примера

```
// Извлечение полей. При этом для полей ID
// и Email я использую просто указатель
// для остальных - временные переменные.
func (u *User) Fields() []interface{} {
    var firstName sql.NullString
    var lastName sql.NullString
    var createdAt pq.NullTime
    var updatedAt pq.NullTime
    var deletedAt pq.NullTime
    // отмеченные крестиком поля
    // требуют проверку на валидность
    // остальные будут записаны в структуру
    // и так (указатель же)
    return []interface{}{
        &u.ID,          // 0
        &firstName,     // 1 x
        &lastName,      // 2 x
        &u.Email,       // 3
        &createdAt,     // 4 x
        &updatedAt,     // 5 x
        &deletedAt,     // 6 x
    }
}

// Присвоение полей обратно. Тут главное не
// напутать. Собственно в этом и весь основной
// гемморрой - для каждого сложного запроса
// знать в каком порядке следуют данные.
func (u *User) Apply(fields ...interface{}) {
    // поля 0 и 3 уже на месте
    firstName := fields[1].(*sql.NullString)
    lastName := fields[2].(*sql.NullString)
    createdAt := fields[4].(*pq.NullTime)
    updatedAt := fields[5].(*pq.NullTime)
    deletedAt := fields[6].(*pq.NullTime)
    if firstName.Valid {
        u.FirstName = firstName.String
    }
    if lastName.Valid {
        u.LastName = lastName.String
    }
    if createdAt.Valid {
        u.CreatedAt = createdAt.Time
    }
    if updatedAt.Valid {
        u.UpdatedAt = updatedAt.Time
    }
    if deletedAt.Valid {
        u.DeletedAt = deletedAt.Time
    }
}
```

Как пользоваться. Итак предположим, что кроме `User` у нас есть ещё `App` и мы делаем `INNER JOIN`, так, что в ответе сначала следует `User` а потом `App`:

```
for rows.Next() {
    usr := new(User)
    app := new(App)
    usrFields := usr.Fields()
    appFields := app.Fields()
    if err := rows.Scan(append(usrFields, appFields...)...); err != nil {
        rows.Close()
        return err
    }
    usr.Apply(usrFields...)
    app.Apply(appFields...)
    //
    // работа с заполненными пользователем и приложением
    //
}
```